# Is there a way to define a List<> of two elements string array?

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, data-structures

I want to build two-dimentional array of strings where length of one dimention is 2. Similar to this

```
string[,] array = new string[,]
{
    {"a", "b"},
    {"c", "d"},
    {"e", "f"},
    {"g", "h"}
}
```

Doing

```
List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();

list.Add(new string[2] {"a", "b"});
list.Add(new string[2] {"c", "d"});
list.Add(new string[2] {"e", "f"});
list.Add(new string[2] {"g", "h"});

list.ToArray();
```

gives me

```
string[][]
```

but not

```
string[,]
```

array.

Just curious, is there some trick to build dynamically

```
string[,]
```

array somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could reasonably easily write an extension method to do it. Something like this (only tested very slightly):

```
public static T[,] ToRectangularArray<T>(this IEnumerable<T[]> source)
{
    if (!source.Any())
    {
        return new T[0,0];
    }

    int width = source.First().Length;
    if (source.Any(array => array.Length != width))
    {
         throw new ArgumentException("All elements must have the same length");
    }

    T[,] ret = new T[source.Count(), width];
    int row = 0;
    foreach (T[] array in source)
    {
       for (int col=0; col < width; col++)
       {
           ret[row, col] = array[col];
       }
       row++;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

It's a slight shame that the above code uses T[] as the element type. Due to generic invariance I can't currently make source `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` which would be nice. An alternative might be to introduce a new type parameter with a constraint:

```
public static T[,] ToRectangularArray<T,U>(this IEnumerable<U> source)
    where U : IEnumerable<T>
```

Somewhat hairy, but it should work. (Obviously the implementation needs some changes too, but the basic principle is the same.)

Comment: Very nice! I am still interested if it is possible to define List<> somehow to enforce it to accept only two-element string arrays?

Comment: There's no way of doing this at compile time, or with List<T> itself. There's another class (can't remember the name at the moment) which will allow you to validate entries as they're added, but that's only at execution time.

Answer (score 20):

You can do this.

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
```

The idea being that the Key Value Pair would mimic the array of strings you replicated.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do it would be to implement the `ToArray()` function yourself. You could implement it within your own collection (i.e. `StringTupleCollection`). This could work the same as `ArrayList` (i.e. internal array increasing in size as needed).

However I'm not sure the advantage of `[x,2]` over `[x][2]` (or even `List<string[2]>` would be significant enough to warrant the effort.

You could also write a `StringTupple` class as:

```
public class StringTupple : KeyValuePair<string, string>
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a struct.  I do this when comparing XML Nodes manually.

```
private struct XmlPair
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string Value { set; get; }
}

List<XmlPair> Pairs = new List<XmlPair>();
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with a `List<string[]>`, as the type `string[,]` is different from `string[]`.

Answer (score 0):

KeyValuePair did not work for me when I had to retrieve the values of the checkboxes on the controller as my model.Roles list was null.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, bool> Role in model.Roles){...}
```

The KeyValuePair structure doesn't have a default parameterless constructor and can't be instantiated by the model binder. I recommend a custom model class for your view that has just those properties. [ASP.NET MVC 3 binding user control of type KeyValuePair to ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538846/asp-net-mvc-3-binding-user-control-of-type-keyvaluepair-to-viewmodel)

I found an implementation of a checkboxlist without the use of html helper at the following link  [CheckboxList in MVC3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872192/checkboxlist-in-mvc3-0)