# Issue with Html.EditorFor on MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, custom-model-binder

I have a view with a form that's is typed to a viewmodel called AddEditItemVM. This viewmodel has the following property:

```
public List<Category> Categories{get;set;}
```

What im trying is two things:

- Render a checkbox foreach Category in the generic category list of my viewmodel.
- Make that when the form is posted receive, in my controller action, the property **Categories** instantiated (**into the instance of AddEditItemVM**)

About the first point, i would like to use any helper (if exists) that renders a group of checkboxes using lambda expressions like (m=>m.Categories), instead to render the checkbox with a foreach into the view.

About the second point, i read that there is one feature in MVC called **Custom Model Binders**. These get values from ValueProviders (querystring, cookies, or Form values) and creates the necessary instances passing it to specific action called after a form was posted. Should i create one custom model binder in order to receive my property Categories instantiated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work

[CheckboxList in MVC3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872192/checkboxlist-in-mvc3-0)