# How do I show checkboxlist in asp.net mvc3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a publishers table and I have titles table. I am using Entity Framework v4.1. A publisher entity has titles property and it signifies how many titles this particular publisher has published (I am using pubs database). I want to create a checkbox list where all the titles are shown (all records of titles table) and the titles which this publisher has published should be checked. How can I do that?

I am only able to produce a DropDownlist so far using this code:

```
<tr>
            <td>
                Titles
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.titles.ToList()[0], new SelectList(ViewBag.titles, "title_id", "notes"))
            </td>
        </tr>
```

How can I convert this to checkbox list?

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT:**
After reading `Brian's` post, I made some progress however when I submit the form no values are found:

I created a partial class of title:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVCWebApp.Models
{
    public partial class title
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my EditorTemplate for checkbox:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MVCWebApp.Models.title>" %>

<%= Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)%>
<%= Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsChecked)%>
<%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.title1)%>
<br />
```

From the page where I need checkboxlist I wrote this code:

```
 <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(p => ViewData["titles"])
            </td>
```

This is the actual (highly ineffecient due to nested loop) controller method which renders the page:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
            using (PubsEntities entities = new PubsEntities())
            {
                publisher pub = entities.publishers.Include("titles").Where(p => p.pub_id == id).First();
                List<title> titles = entities.titles.ToList();
                foreach (var item in pub.titles)
                {
                   title tit = (from titleItem in titles where item.pub_id == titleItem.pub_id select item).First();
                    tit.IsChecked = true;
                }
                ViewData["titles"] = titles;
                return View(pub);
            }
        }
```

I get the master list of titles and those titles are published by a particular publisher is checked. However when the form is posted, the values are all **null**

This is my update method where the form is posted:

```
 public ActionResult Update(publisher modifiedPub, List<title> selectedTitle )
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return View("Edit", modifiedPub);

            using (PubsEntities entities = new PubsEntities())
            {

                publisher pub = entities.publishers.Where(p => p.pub_id == modifiedPub.pub_id).First();
                pub.pub_name = modifiedPub.pub_name;
                pub.state = modifiedPub.state;

                entities.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Publishers");
            }
        }
```

Here the selectedTitle is null and even in modifiedPub.titles the count is 0. Can anybody tell me where is it wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

P.S: Do we really have to do so much just to get checkboxlist?

Comment: See this stackoverflow post;

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872192/checkboxlist-in-mvc3-0][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872192/checkboxlist-in-mvc3-0

Comment: @Brian: I am confused. Is this really what I am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line is your problem:

```
@Html.EditorFor(p => ViewData["titles"])
```

Everytime you use the `ViewData/ViewBag` keywords in an ASP.NET MVC application you will have problems. The correct way of doing this is to use a view model. In this view model you will have a property `Titles` which will be a collection of the type you defined. And in your view you will simply:

```
@Html.EditorFor(p => p.Titles)
```

This of course would mean that you will have to modify your `Edit` controller action so that instead of returning this `pub` domain model to the view it uses your actual real view model.

Like this:

```
public class TitleViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}

public class PublisherViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<TitleViewModel> Titles { get; set; }

    ... some other properties of a publisher that you want to work on in your view    
}
```

and the controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
{
    var publisher = _service.GetPublisher(id);

    var viewModel = new PublisherViewModel
    {
        Titles = publisher.Titles.Select(x => new TitleViewModel
        {
            Id = x.Name,
            IsChecked = true
        })
    };

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(PublisherViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)    
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    var publisher = ... map the view model to a domain model
    _service.UpdatePublisher(publisher);

    return RedirectToAction("Publishers");
}
```

Comment: I know but that is not what I want. `p.Titles` will only be a collection of titles which has been published by a particular publisher. I want to show all the records of titles tables that is why I stored it in ViewData. Please let me know if I am not clear about my requirement.

Comment: Oh my god. I got your point. But this is too much code just to get 1 checkboxlist. Is there no other solution for this? Also I noticed nobody teaches these real world things in any tutorial. They just show how to show textbox and get data inside it.

Comment: @Bob Lee Swagger, you could use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)  to perform the mapping between your domain models and your view models. It would drastically simplify your controller actions where, as I showed in my post, the mapping was done manually.

Comment: Ok! one more thing. It should not be `Titles = publisher.Titles(...)` rather it should be `Titles = context.Titles(...)` because I need all titles to show up and then loop over titles and check the required ones (which are present in publisher.titles).