# Form processing and validation in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. I am working on localhost to create my project in ASP.NET MVC. I am using .NET Framework 3.5  and MVC 1.0 and Visual Studio 2008 for development. SQL Server 2008 is where I have created my databases at present.

My project involves creating 2 pages:

1) In 1st page I have user name and password text box fields. I have a submit button. On click of submit button I want to first hash password using *SHA-1* hashing and then store the hash in the appropriate column of my database. So I need some idea on how to do this?

2) Secondly, I have a page that contains a dropdown list and checkboxes and again a submit button. When user selects any item of dropdown list, checks the checkboxes he wants and clicks submit button, I want to store item selected in drop down list and checkbox values checked by user in 2 different columns of my database. So here I want to know whether I can use String Array to contain checkbox values and then on submit apply a loop to insert each individual value in my column.

Please can anyone tell me whether this is possible?  If yes, how to go about it. Also, if there are better ways to do it please suggest me.

Comment: why are you using asp mvc 1.0?

Comment: I did switch over to MVC 3 recently. Just mentioned MVC 1.0 because I have built few modules of my project using it long back and now completing the remaining.

Comment: Its possible.  Yes.  You should ask two separate questions. Separately, both of these questions are duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could use the [SHA1Managed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s02tk69a.aspx) class. For increased security when dealing with storing hashes into the database it is recommended to [use a salt](http://www.obviex.com/samples/hash.aspx) as well.
2. You could define a view model containing 3 properties: a string property which will hold the selected dropdown value, an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property to hold the list of items for the dropdown and finally an `IEnumerable<CheckViewModel>` to hold the values of the checkboxes. The `CheckViewModel` will be a view model with 2 properties: a string property which will hold the value of the checkbox and a boolean property which will indicate whether it is checked or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Are there any tutorials on the same that I could refer to?

Comment: @Parth_90, if you talk about the second part of your question you may take a look at the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4872228/29407. It's about ASP.NET MVC 3 and it won't work for ASP.NET MVC 1 since it doesn't support strongly typed helpers and editor templates but you could tweak it and using a foreach loop generate the proper markup in the view.