# MVC3 RadioButtonFor value is not binded to the model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, binding, model, radiobuttonfor

I have a MVC3 Razor form. It have a radiobutton list and some another text fields. When I press submit controller post action get the view model, which have all fields seted correctly, except RegionID.

**Model:**

```
    namespace SSHS.Models.RecorderModels
    {
        public class CreateViewModel
        {
             ...
             public int RegionID { get; set; }
             ...
        }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
    namespace SSHS.Controllers
    {
        public class RecorderController : Controller
        {
            ...
            public ActionResult Create()
            {
                EntrantDBEntities db = new EntrantDBEntities();

                List Regions = new List(db.Region); 
                List Schools = new List(db.School);
                List Settlements = new List(db.settlement);

                CreateViewModel newEntr = new CreateViewModel();

                ViewBag.Regions = Regions;
                ViewBag.Schools = Schools;
                ViewBag.Settlements = Settlements;

                return View(newEntr);
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Create(CreateViewModel m)
            {
                EntrantDBEntities db = new EntrantDBEntities();

                Entrant e = new Entrant()
                {
                    FatherName = m.FatherName,
                    Lastname = m.LastName,
                    LocalAddress = m.LocalAddress,
                    Name = m.Name,
                    RegionID = m.RegionID,
                    PassportID = m.PassportID,
                    SchoolID = m.SchoolID,
                    SettlementID = m.SattlementID,
                    TaxID = m.TaxID,
                };

                db.Entrant.AddObject(e);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
    }
```

**View:**

```
    @model SSHS.Models.RecorderModels.CreateViewModel
    @using SSHS.Models 

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Recorder", FormMethod.Post))
    {       
    
    
        @foreach (Region item in ViewBag.Regions)
        {
           
           @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.RegionID, item.RegionID)
           @Html.Label(item.RegionName) - @item.RegionID
           
        }
    
          ...
          ...    
    
    }
```

The Create(CreateViewModel m) method gets data from all textboxes normaly, but RegionID always is 0.

Comment: Radio button is used for true/false state. According your case you might have used Select List. Try to check Request["YourRegionRadioId"] in [HttpPost] Create method, if it has any value.

Comment: Request["RegionSelect"] not set to an instance of an object

Comment: This should work. I suspect that the code you are showing us is somehow not your actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you planning to fill radio button with `int` ? It have two states: checked and not. Could you tell us, what are you trying to do? Make radio group? Use `bool` for `RadioButtonFor`.

**Added:**

You need to write something like this: [CheckboxList in MVC3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872192/checkboxlist-in-mvc3-0) (in your example you will have radio buttons)

Comment: I want to get the radio group for more than 2 positions and get the selected position in post method.

Comment: @Bill Mustdie What do you mean 'more than 2 positions'?

Comment: [ ]Position1 [x]Position2 [ ]position3.... Is it posible using standart MVC helpers?

Comment: Yes, look at link I posted before. You just need extra field for control state, your RegionID need to be hidden field.