# create dynamic checkbox on the basis of value in my model

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working in MVC 4, and in my View i am writing this code to generate the checkbox:

```
<tr class="formSectionField clearfix">
   <td>
      <label id="lblStoreList" class="formSectionLabel">Title:</label>
   </td>
   <td>
     <div class="txtInput input323">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.StoreList, new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>()))
     </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Initially, i am just telling MVC framework, that it will have a checbox, but i want to have **n number** of checkbox based upon the value that is contained in my model.

**How could i achieve that?**

Below is the JS code with AJAX which will generate my dynamic checkbox:

```
function BindTitle() {
    $.ajax({
        "url": "/Admin/GetTitleList/",
        "type": "get",
        "dataType": "json",
        "success": function (data) {
            var items = $('#TitleId');
            items.empty();
            $.each(data, function (i, drdData) {
                items.append($('<checkbox/>', { value: drdData.Value, html: drdData.Text }));
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**Hope i made you clear with this, in any case if you want further suggestion, please feel free to ask**

Comment: Take a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872192/checkboxlist-in-mvc3-0) asnswer, I think it is the same in MVC 3 and MVC 4.

Comment: @Daniele thanks but it didn't work

Comment: use ViewBag to get model data for your particular property and then use @foreach(...){}