# ASP.NET MVC: Checkbox for each item, then collect selected items in a variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

On one of my index pages: `Course/Index` in my Contoso University MVC project, I've added a checkbox for each `Course` item, and a button: "Retrieve Students" that when clicked, will retrieve all Students who are enrolled in the selected Courses. I've successfully redirected the program execution to call inside Action:  `StudentsEnrolledInSelectedCourses ()` inside my Controller: `CourseController.cs` when I click "Retrieve Students".  Now I'm trying to add logic in `StudentsEnrolleInSelectedCourses ()` to retrieve all the Course items selected, and retrieve all Students who are enrolled in the selected Courses. However, I don't know the correct way to check if a Course item has been selected. I've added a "Selected" field in the Course Model: Course.cs, however, this value is not updated in the database when the user selects the Course. I checked this in the SQL Server Object Explorer. What's the correct way to implement a Checkbox feature, and when to check if an item has been checked/selected?

```
CourseController.cs:

namespace ContosoUniversity.Controllers
{


 public class CourseController : Controller
    {
        private SchoolContext db = new SchoolContext();

        public void StudentsEnrolledInSelectedCourses ()
        {
            //Iterate thru Each Course Item, 
            //if it's selected add to list?
            //Does act of selecting a Course item update its Selected bool?
            //Must manually update?

            IQueryable<Course> courses = db.Courses
            .Where(c => c.Selected == true)
            .OrderBy(d => d.CourseID)
            .Include(d => d.Title);


            foreach (var c in courses)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(c.Title);
                Debug.WriteLine(c.Selected);
            }
        }
         ...
    }
 }



Course.cs:

namespace ContosoUniversity.Models
{
    public class Course
    {

        [Display(Name = "Select")]
        public bool Selected { get; set; }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [Display(Name = "Number")]
        public int CourseID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Range(0, 5)]
        public int Credits { get; set; }

        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }



        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
    }
}

Views/Course/Index.cshtml:

@model IEnumerable<ContosoUniversity.Models.Course>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Courses";
}

<h2>Courses</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        Select Department: @Html.DropDownList("SelectedDepartment", "All")
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </p>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("StudentsEnrolledInSelectedCourses", "Course", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
        Retrieve All Students taking Selected Courses
        <input type="submit" value="Retrieve Students"/>
    </p>
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
           Select
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CourseID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Credits)
        </th>
        <th>
            Department
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Selected)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CourseID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Credits)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.CourseID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.CourseID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.CourseID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Comment: below is link for model list binding. click and learn /

Comment: possible duplicate of [CheckboxList in MVC3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872192/checkboxlist-in-mvc3-0)

Comment: This question has an excellent answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872192/checkboxlist-in-mvc3-0

Comment: You need a `for` loop (not `foreach` which is creating invalid html and giving all the checkboxes the same `name` and `id` attributes). `for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { @Html.CheckboxFor(m => m[i].Selected) ...}`