# ASP.NET MVC 3 binding user control of type KeyValuePair to ViewModel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, user-controls

I have created a special User Control which inherits KeyValuePair.
Inside my ViewModel, there is a property called lookup

```
[UIHint("Lookup")]
public KeyValuePair<string, string> lookup { get; set; }
```

User Control is

```
Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Value, new { id = "Name", style = "width: 200px; background-color: #C0C0C0" })

Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Key, new { id="Guid"})
```

The user Control has some Jquery statements which set the value of the TextBox and the Hidden field.

When I do a DEBUG to the POST method of the Controller, I see no value inside the Lookup property?!

But If I changed the type of the property to string instead of KeyValuePair
and also change the type of the User Control, I see a value.

I think I'm very close but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `KeyValuePair` structure doesn't have a default parameterless constructor and can't be instantiated by the model binder.  I recommend a custom model class for your view that has just those properties.

```
public class CustomControlViewModel
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Transform your KVP into this model class for your view and/or use this class as the parameter on your action.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Lookup()
{
    return View( new CustomControlViewModel { Value = kvp.Value, Key = kvp.Key } );
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Lookup( CustomControlViewModel lookup )
{
     ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I want.

Comment: Why it doesn't work if it works properly using Dictionary, that implements <IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>> ?

Comment: @MarioLevrero I assume (without checking) that the model binder for a dictionary uses the Add method to update the dictionary.